# Cross domain fetch switching in prod vs dev

Tags: javascript, react.js, cors

I'm beginning a redesign of the front end of my Flask app which currently generates Jinja2 template-based html pages. I am trying to develop a new front end in React, but I want the current front end to continue to exist. Much like Reddit, I want my current front end to exist at old.anno.wiki and the new front end to exist at anno.wiki, but I would like to continue to use all the same backend code.

There are several ways to achieve this and the idea that I most like is that I move the entire app to old.anno.wiki and write a React app at anno.wiki that queries old.anno.wiki's to-be-developed api. This runs into problems with CORS, and, more importantly, with issues of development vs production fetching.

(note: right now I'm temporarily using new.anno.wiki for the new react front end while I continue to use anno.wiki for the old one as I develop the new).

As I develop, while in dev I'd like to query the Flask api running in docker locally, in production I'd like to query the api currently at anno.wiki/api. To do this I set the [React proxy to "http://localhost:5000"](https://github.com/malan88/icc-frontend/blob/master/package.json#L3) and wrote a helper function to get the domain to query in my code:

```
const URL = 'https://anno.wiki';

const getHome = () => {
  const url = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? '' : URL;
  return url
}
```

I then, in all my fetches, query this and use it to precede whatever route I query, like so:

```
  const [currentTime, setCurrentTime] = useState(0);
  const url = getHome();

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(url + '/api/time').then(res => res.json()).then(data => {
      setCurrentTime(data.time);
    });
  }, [url]);
```

I am concerned that this might not be the way to do this. Is this secure? I imagine that by concatenating with `+` it is less efficient than using template literals, but that is not my concern. My concern is that this might have hidden consequences that I am unaware of, either security implications or efficiency problems.

Any advice would be very much appreciated.